# Android unit testing verify that OnCreate sends intent and that fragment shown

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I have an Android app in which the starting Activity starts an IntentService. I would like to know how to test that this intent is sent. I'm using Robolectric, but I'm just starting, so I could remove it if needed.

I also have my onCreate showing a fragment based on whether some data is loaded or not. This comes from a singleton. I'd like to know how to test whether that fragment is shown or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Testing `Service` `Intent`s

To test the `IntentService` your test can use `Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getNextStartedService()` which will return the `Intent` object used to start the service. You can then perform assertions on the Intent to verify that the action is as expected.

```
@Test
public void shouldStartMyIntentService() throws Exception {
    Intent serviceIntent = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getNextStartedService();
    assertEquals("MY_INTENT_ACTION", serviceIntent.getAction());
}
```

### Verifying that a `Fragment` is visible

A simple way to verify that a fragment is visible is to perform a `findViewById` on the containing `Activity` for a view in the fragment:

```
@Test
public void shouldShowPuppyFragment() throws Exception {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(PuppyAndKittenActivity.class).create().visible().get();
    assertEquals(View.VISIBLE, activity.findViewById(R.id.puppies).getVisibility());
    assertNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.kittens));
}
```

---

#### Side note...

I would **highly** recommend using the Robolectric 2.2-SNAPSHOT version right now. A lot of really good changes have gone in since 2.1.1 was released and I'm not sure when a new release will be made. Robolectric is a constant work in progress and it's improving on a regular basis.

Comment: I'm 90% sure I'm using 2.2-SNAPSHOT, but I'll double check.

As far as the first one goes, will that work for an Intent I fire off during OnCreate?

Comment: Awesome! The more people using the latest and greatest helps tighten feedback loops when awesome changes break unique corners of the Android universe and thus bugs get fixed faster.